# Could not display DNS Resolver Cache in Windows Server 2008 R2 in Hyper-V environment

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2, ip, hyper-v, domain-name

Currently I had a Windows Server 2008 R2 running in Hyper-V, previously it still able to access any kind of website with domain name. Recently, it failed to do that any more, and I found out that I can still access website with IP address, but not domain name, and once I tried manually configure the *hosts* file (located in system32/drivers/etc/), the domain name works again. I also tried flushdns, restart server, restart router, restart anything that I could.

Anyone know how to resolve this?

FIY: The server is a file server and deployment server, mainly for users logged in for building deployment and testing purpose. It does not have DNS server roles.

Comment: so within the guest you don't get a result for "nslookup serverfault.com"  if not do a ipconfig /all look at the dns settings are they correct?

Comment: "DNS request timed out" is the result it returned when I do nslookup, I've checked the dns setting, it's the same since the first day I configured it, and same with any other server as well.

Comment: Are you able to see DNS traffic on your edge firewall from this server? Is it maybe blocking it for some reason?

Comment: How do I check on DNS traffic? mind sharing?

Comment: That depends on your firewall on how to do it, but have a look for Port 53, UDP traffic

Comment: Just run some monitoring using wireshark on UDP Port 53, and notice some red color label when I tried to ping www.google.com, it comes with this error: 
Header checksum: 0x000 [incorrect, should be 0xb3d2 (maybe caused by "IP checksum offload"?]

But I'm not sure what is that, how can I make it go away?

Comment: Just disable it in wireshark: `Menu: Edit > Preferences > Protocols > IPv4 > Validate the IPv4 checksum if possible (uncheck this box)` I don't think it has something to do with your problem.
Is there a reply to that packet?

Comment: There's no query respond from any query sent, should I just re-install the network adapter?

Comment: What does the DNS server have set as forwarders? (Ie. servers to use when result is not known locally.)

Comment: Do you mean the DNS server on the Hyper-V server or the router? Sorry not really into DNS server thing. Anyway, we do not have DNS server setup here, and didn't set any forwarder too. The setup here is quite simple, computer connected to router, router to modem, that's it.

Comment: so this server has worked before in this configuration, can it ping the dns server?

Comment: Yes, it is working for the past few months with the exactly same configuration. It can ping to the router (if that's the dns server you mean), it also can ping other server with their server-name or pc with pc-name

Answer (score -1):

Open a command prompt and type "ipconfig /all".

This will list the DNS servers that your network adapter is using. If that is blank or points to somewhere strange, that is a likely source of your problem. Whatever is specified as your network adapter's DNS servers is always the place it will ask for DNS resolution, whether that destination is real or not.

The quickest way to get to where you need to fix it in Server 2008 is to open a run box and type 'ncpa.cpl'. This will fire up your network connections. Go to the properties of the problematic virtual NIC (you said this is on Hyper-V, right?), configure IPv4, and specify your DNS servers. If they are being assigned automatically, then that means DHCP isn't supplying the correct info. Manually type them in. If all you need is name resolution for websites outside your organization, Google's public DNS server of 8.8.8.8 works fine.

Comment: Just had the network adapter DNS for Hyper-V set to 8.8.8.8, but it is still now working, I am able to ping 8.8.8.8, but not www.google.com